# Build the edge-vertex topology from a polyline feature class in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, line, topology

I have a polyline feature class called line_1. What I want to achieve is the edge_vertex topology. Specifically,

1. I want to generate a new polyine feature class called line_1_new, by adding two new columns to line_1, start_v_id and end_v_id.
2. I want to generate a point feature class from line_1. The point feature has an attribute called v_id, corresponding to the start_v_id and end_v_id attributes.

I have used the method of *Feature Vertices To Points* to generate a point feature class of both ends of the lines. However, the point feature does not contain the topology explicitly. For example, if two lines intersect at a junction, this method will generate two points corresponding to the junction, even though these two points have the same coordinates.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Unfortunately, questions here not only need to state what you want, but what you have done, and where you are stuck. Associating points with near neighbors seems to be your next step, though your goal is not completely clear.

Comment: Collect events will help to make one vertex from each 'stack' of vertices, but be careful, it only works reliably in a projected coordinate system. I would suggest though that this is something best done in arcpy, ArcObjects or via the network analyst extension. Do you have any python/ArcObjects ability?

Comment: Are line endpoints snapped to each other? Do any lines cross themselves, or other line features?